# IPv6 Address not setting

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

I am having a problem setting up IPv6 Address on ubuntu 10.04.I have disabled my network-manager. My /etc/network/interface file looks like this:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
pre-up modeprobe ipv6
address fe80::1
netmask 10
gateway fe80::2
```

I have setup my ip address as fe80::1 but when I up eth0 ifconfig shows

```
inet6 addr:  fe80::a00:27ff:fe1e:5edf/64 Scope:Link
```

Why does it show a different IP address?

When I run

```
ping6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1e:5edf/64
```

It tell me unknown host. Why ?

Comment: What command are you using to "up eth0"? Is it `ifup` or `ifconfig eth0 up`?

Comment: `ifconfig eth0 up`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that you use *ifconfig* to bring the interface up. In this case, your problem is that ***ifconfig* does not use the `interfaces` file** (it only tells the interface to start receiving packets). This configuration file is specific to Debian/Ubuntu and is only read by the *ifupdown* tools `ifup` and `ifdown`. So you would have to use:

```
ifup eth0
```

Even then, your configuration will be rejected because the configuration file syntax uses "**`iface`**", not "`interface`", to denote a new logical interface. (See the *interfaces(5)* manual for full syntax description.)

(Your `pre-up` line is also 1) unnecessary: it's done automatically, and 2) mistyped: it's "`modprobe`".)

---

The `fe80::a00:27ff:fe1e:5edf` address is shown not because of any configuration, but because IPv6 requires it. Every interface is required to have a *link-local* address based on the "interface ID" (its MAC address); these addresses are added automatically by the Linux kernel.

(Remember that an interface can have many addresses. You can have both `fe80::1` and `fe80::a00:27ff:fe1e:5edf` on the same interface, and it will still work.)

Also remember that the `fe80::/10` addresses are **link-local** – in other words, they [are never routed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.6), and the `gateway` configuration setting is meaningless.

This means that whenever you try to access a link-local address, you must manually specify the interface to use – this is done by [adding a **zone index**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Link-local_addresses_and_zone_indices) to the address. (On Linux, the zone index is the same as interface name.) For example, to connect over *eth0*, you have to add `%eth0`:

`ping6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1e:5edf%eth0`

(Oliver Salzburg's answer is also correct – you must not specify a subnet mask when referring to a single host.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to supply a subnet mask for `ping`.

```
ping6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1e:5edf
```

Should be fine.

Comment: without the subnet mask I get `connect: Invalid argument`

Comment: thanks, you were right about the subnet mask, although I did need to specify interface address using -I option or as mentioned in grawity's answer.